# How to manage & define all data analytics we send from the application?

Tags: android, ios, analytics, data-analysis, mobile-analytics

We are developing mobile application.
When we define a feature, we define also the data analytic events that we should report from the application. 
We have some issues where the analytics sometimes doesn't have the exact name and we have differences from Android & iOS.
Also we want to see in one place what the current events that we currently have.

I'm looking for a tool / service that will give me the following:
1. Define data analytics events
2. Export this to Android / iOS files so they will use the same naming convention.

For example, today we define in a document that we want to see the event: "Screen Opened" with the name "Login".
Every developer, iOS / Android, copy the name of the event to his code, one can write "Screen Opened" with "Login" and one with mistake "Log in".
Then the analysis is really hard. 
More than that, someday we want to see if we have already defined this event, so we want one place to take a look on.

Is there anything like that in the market?

Comment: Your question is fairly vague/broad.  You might want to include some sample data which, for example, demonstrates the issue which is happening on Android versus iOS.

Comment: I have added more details.

Comment: Tools like : https://betalist.com/startups/tracking-plan or Segment Protocols